# Html get color in Rgb

Tags: javascript, html, colors

Well i need to do a little projet in webgl and need to pass the color from the html to the javascript, the thing is that i need that color in Rgb to working direcrly with webGl, what i need to know is if there is a way using html5 to get the color in rgb from the input.

Im doing this:

```
<input type="color" onchange="cor()" id="color">
```

the prob here is if i try to get this color he gives me the hexadecimal value, i know that via javascript with a function i can convert the hexadecimal to rgb but i need to know if there is a easier way to do this and put to work.

Answer (score 11):

Fortunately color values in HTML5 are only valid if they're in the `#XXXXXX` format (meaning `rgb(...)` and `#XXX` are invalid). We can use this to our advantage as we always know exactly where the RGB positions will be in the resulting value:

```
#XXXXXX
#RRGGBB
```

To convert this to `rgb(...)`, we simply need to strip out the `#` character and convert the `RR`, `GG` and `BB` values to decimal:

```
// #XXXXXX -> ["XX", "XX", "XX"]
var value = value.match(/[A-Za-z0-9]{2}/g);

// ["XX", "XX", "XX"] -> [n, n, n]
value = value.map(function(v) { return parseInt(v, 16) });

// [n, n, n] -> rgb(n,n,n)
return "rgb(" + value.join(",") + ")";
```

And with the beauty of JavaScript, we can do this all on one line of code:

```
return "rgb(" + "#FF0000".match(/[A-Za-z0-9]{2}/g).map(function(v) { return parseInt(v, 16) }).join(",") + ")";
-> "rgb(255,0,0)"
```

Comment: thanks, soo much improvement on Html5 why they just dont put a inputType=RgbColor or something

Comment: @FilipeCosta probably because there are a *lot* of different colour types. The hexadecimal notation itself has 4 recognised formats that I'm aware of (`#RGB`, `#RGBA`, `#RRGGBB` and `#RRGGBBAA`). There'd need to be lengthy discussions about what formats should be accepted. I imagine we'll probably see something like this in a future edition of HTML though.